# Visualization of a function in which the range of values and functions change

Tags: plotting

I have this function

[image]

I want to visualize this function，So I use this

```mathematica
data = Table[{b, #, (b + #)/(b^2 + #)}, {b, 1/5, 5*#}] & /@ 
   Range[0.3, 0.8, 0.001];
Flatten[data, 1] // Point // Graphics3D
```

get this

[image]

This image is very strange and it doesn't feel like what I wanted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach is alright but you need the `ListPlot3D` function.You need to check documentation properly .

```
data = Table[{b, #, (b + #)/(b^2 + #)}, {b, 1/5, 5*#}]& /@ Range[0.3, 0.8, 0.001];
ListPlot3D[Flatten[data, 1]]
```

But you can allow mathematica to do the heavy lifting. Let's define your simple and bounded 2D region like this.

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[1/2 < b <= 5 c && 0.3 < c < 0.8, {b, c}];
RegionPlot[reg, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Now get a continuous 3D plot of the surface of interest.

```
Plot3D[(b + c)/(b^2 + c), {b, c} \[Element] reg]
```

[image]

It is also possible to get the surface without defining the region but using the `RegionFunction` option of `Plot3D` like this.

```
Plot3D[(b + c)/(b^2 + c), {b, 1/2, 4.5}, {c, 0.25, 0.85}, 
RegionFunction -> Function[{b, c, z}, 1/2 < b <= 5 c && 0.3 < c < 0.8]]
```